# React native iOS app - crashing on release mode

Tags: react-native, release

HI I am new to  react native and trying to do a release build. I have changed the jsCodeLocation to the jsbundle. Also have changed the schema to run on release mode. but when i run the app and click a button the whole app is crashing.

I followed the example from the following url

https://medium.com/react-native-development/deploying-a-react-native-app-for-ios-pt-1-a79dfd15acb8

Here is the code for button click

```
moveToJoinScreen(){
    this.props.navigation.navigate('JoinNowScreen')
}
```

Here is the error

```
2017-10-25 17:10:50.240 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] undefined is not an object (evaluating 'console.tron.log')

2017-10-25 17:10:50.264 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'console.tron.log')

2017-10-25 17:10:50.270 StudentCardApp[1101:710561] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'console.tron.log')', reason: 'Unhandled JS Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'console.tro..., stack:

<unknown>@1222:448

navigate@722:256

value@779:867

onPress@779:1314

touchableHandlePress@575:1882

_performSideEffectsForTransition@488:8512

_receiveSignal@488:7295

touchableHandleResponderRelease@488:4739

Gt@435:21830

invokeGuardedCallback@435:22155

invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError@435:22277

C@435:1870

y@435:2072

nn@435:22882

rn@435:22989

P@435:3019

processEventQueue@435:23832

G@435:5536

handleTopLevel@435:27383

<unknown>@435:28885

qn@435:28110

z@435:6018

perform@436:3484

batchedUpdates@436:18575

Ce@435:10516

Q@435:6049

K@435:6111

_receiveRootNodeIDEvent@435:28856

receiveTouches@435:29236

value@340:3107

<unknown>@340:840

value@340:2535

value@340:812

'

*** First throw call stack:

(0x2488f91b 0x2402ae17 0x2488f861 0x8d2c9 0x8817f 0x248944c4 0x247ba87d 0x247be2f7 0x8b1df 0xd19e9 0xd1839 0x53ab7f 0x545493 0x53dde1 0x546ecf 0x5467cf 0x245c1b29 0x245c1718)

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

It runs fine on debug mode. Can some one please help me fix this. Thanks in advance

Comment: One good advice is to use `__DEV__ && console.tron.log('something')` for 100% proof when logging stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are using [Reactotron](https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron).
the thing is Reactotron is not available in non-DEV builds.
Check this issue where it's discussed https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron/issues/433

Answer (score 1):

I solved issue by:

1. Using VS Code
2. Click the magnifier button on the top left, Search and Replace across workspace,  type `console.tron.log` and replace with `if (__DEV__) console.tron.log`
3. File>Save all.
4. Success.

Answer (score 0):

ended up using this plug in

https://github.com/infinitered/babel-plugin-ignite-ignore-reactotron

this removes the Reacrtotron.

more explanation on the following link

https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron/issues/433